# Flutter - How to launch URL despite bad status code

Tags: http, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Using [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-) I can launch a url, say https://httpstat.us/200 which simulates status code 200: ok and `url_launcher` launches this url fine.

I'm looking for a way in which to force `url_launcher` to launch a different, often broken link such as https://httpstat.us/204 which returns status code 204: no content.

In my code I launch run my specific `launch_url` algorithm on button press, but as I execute this nothing happens.

This is my console error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(188)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:363))
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
#3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
#4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
#6      HomePageState._launchString (package:web_check/main.dart:41:36)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
#8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
#9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
#10     TapGestureRecog<…>
```

Thanks, Jake

Comment: You could make an HTTP request in Dart code and only open with url_launcher when you get back 200 OK. Otherwise I'd suggest to create a feature request in github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new to not throw an exception in that case.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks Günter, I think I’ll have to issue a feature request as I would still like the website to load but in the meantime I’ll try out the HTTP request. Thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hey Günter, while waiting for a response from GitHub (I realise you have replied and are waiting for me to follow up) I found a solution to this issue, as I've realised I don't need the page to load for `url_launcher` to perform its required task - I'll be following up this stack question with an answer soon.  Can I just terminate my question over at GitHub or are there any extra steps before I do this?  Thanks

Comment: You can close your own issues at any time without any further steps.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks Günter, had to be safe.